# ASP.NET MVC Routing Debugger - Do I have to recompile to switch back from debugger to my application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Looking into [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx).  It works as described. Looks like I have to recompile to switch back from debugger to browse my application. Is there a simpler way to switch or is this they way it works?

Answer (score 1):

I took the code and refactored it to its own controller/view/model. That way, I navigate to the RouteDebugger View when I need it.

I added a text input box to enter my URL that I want to debug on the View.